# NetBeans 7.0, how to go to end of line?

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm learning to really like vi, and can't stand writing code in netbeans anymore without being able to jump to the end of a line. It's killing me, and I can't find it in the shorcuts or even how to add it. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Erm ... ever use a word processor?

Comment: heh, yeah, to write papers in school. ctrl+s, ctrl+b, ctrl+u is about all you needed.

Comment: Although, it's almost a trick question. This damn macbook pro my new gig supplied doesn't *have* an `end` key. Really annoying when you've been using one for years.

Comment: To do home and end keys on a Mac press fn+left/right arrows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to **Tools : Options : Keymap** and search for "Insertion Point to End of Line" which mysteriously defaults to the `End` key. ;) You should be able to reassign any other shortcut to it.

Answer (score 3):

U Can Use `Ctrl+;` to add semicolon at the end of Line and still in your position

Or

```
Ctrl+Shift+;
```

to add semicolon at the end of line and change position to new line.

Comment: this doesn't support anymore